# How to include all files in dojo build layer?

Tags: build, dojo

I have a profile defined like this:

```
var profile = {
    ....
    layers: {
       "dojo/dojo": {
            include: ["dojo/main" ],
            customBase: true,
            boot: true
        }
       , "my/widget": { include: [ 
                 "my/widget/AuthorWidget",
                 "my/widget/templates/AuthorWidget.html" ] 
       }
    },
....
}
```

This does what I want. It creates files dojo.js and widget.js which include all I need.

Is there any beter way how to include all files from my/widget, without listing them in include: ? AuthorWidget.js looks like this:

```
define([
    "dojo/_base/declare",
    "dijit/_WidgetBase",
    "dijit/_TemplatedMixin",
    "dojo/text!./templates/AuthorWidget.html",
    "dojo/dom-style",
....
```

So I would expected to include every dependent widgets from my/widget/templates/AuthorWidget.html. Unfortunatelly, I have have this file in the include: array, otherwise dijig/form/Button is not included in the result. (i have [button type="button" data-dojo-type="dijit/form/Button"]Click Me![/button] in the AuthorWidget.html)

my.profile.js:

```
var profile = (function(){
    return {
        basePath: "./src",
        releaseDir: "../release",
        releaseName: "my",
        action: "release",
        defaultConfig: {
            async: 1
        },

        packages:[{
            name: "dojo",
            location: "dojo"
        },{
            name: "dijit",
            location: "dijit"
        },{
            name: "dojox",
            location: "dojox"
        },{
            name: "my",
            location: "../js/my",
            destLocation: "myapp"
        }],
        layers: {
            "dojo/dojo": {
                include: ["dojo/main" ],
                customBase: true,
                boot: true
            }
           //this works
           //, "my/widget": { include: [ "my/widget/AuthorWidget", "my/widget/templates/AuthorWidget.html" ] }
           //this doesnt include Button widget required by AuthorWidget.html
           , "my/widget": { include: [ "my/widget/all" ] }
        },
        layerOptimize: "closure",
        optimize: "closure",
        cssOptimize: "comments",
        mini: true,
        stripConsole: "warn",
        selectorEngine: "lite"
    };
})();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Straight answer to your question, as far as I know is NO. You need to list your dependencies, in one way or another.

But you can create an `all.js` file, which is basically a module that can contain all  dependencies for your custom widgets.

This give you the advantage of keeping your dependencies definition outside  `.profile.js`.

As example of usage could be creating `all.js` automatically using a custom made tool so you do not need to update all dependencies and their path manually when you modules are created in your app.

Example of `all.js` (this file can be kept updated manually or with some custom made tool):

```
require([
    'my/widget/AuthorWidget',
    'my/widget/AuthorWidget2,
     ...
]);
```

In your `profile.js` include only `all.js`:

```
var profile = {
    ....
    layers: {
       "dojo/dojo": {
            include: ["dojo/main" ],
            customBase: true,
            boot: true
        }
       , "my/widget": { include: [ 
                 "all"
          ] 
       }
    },
....
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. This works for the AuthorWidget.js, but not for the my/widget/templates/AuthorWidget.html.  In authorWidget.html is button with data-dojo-type="dijit/form/Button" attribute and dijit/form/Button is not included in the result. If I keep "my/widget/templates/AuthorWidget.html" in the profile.js/include array, then it works. If I move it to all.js, it doesnt...

Comment: @Petr try to set up package property on your .profile.js you need to specify the right path for dijit there. More info here  about all options can be found here: https://dojotoolkit.org/documentation/tutorials/1.10/build/ let be know if you were able to fix it :)

Comment: I have read this and I have no idea what could by wrong. As I said, putting  "my/widget/templates/AuthorWidget.html" into my.profile.js works correctly (include dijit/form/Button into the result widget.js). But moving this from my.profile.js to all.js, it stop to include the dijit/form/Button. It works for all other dependencies in AuthorWidget - it even include the content of AuthorWidget.html in the result.

Comment: @Petr It looks like an issue when the build resolve your modules. Could you please post your full version of .profile.js and folder structure of your project? I can try to have a look.

Comment: I find out where was the problem. I have not required dijit/form/Button in my AuthorWidget.js file. It is required to require all widgets used in a template (and not to expect parsr.parse() to download it)